# How to use bash script to flip the orientation of my screen?

Tags: linux, bash

So I'm trying to flip the screen of my laptop/convertible, but I need to set a variable to save the screen state....  I'm trying to use this code, but it's not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( SCREEN == 1 ))
then
    echo 'flip1'
    xrandr -o normal
    xinput set-prop 'Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
    export SCREEN=0
else
    echo 'flip2'
    xrandr -o normal
    xinput set-prop 'Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
    export SCREEN=1
fi
```

I already export SCREEN at start-up, but this script doesn't seem to change it, and I can't find out why!  I don't really care if I use an environment variable, but I do need to save the state that the screen is in.  Any help is welcome.  Thank you!

Comment: It depends on how you execute your script. If you run it with a new instance of Bash then certainly any change would be meaningless since the environment variables would be lost after the shell exits and returns control to the caller. Perhaps posting the code that executes the script would be helpful.

Comment: The export statement makes a variable available to the *children* of the shell and not to the rest of the world. In particular, not to the parent shell. It's best to save the state to a file and read it each time you want to refer to it, i.e. `echo flip1 > /some/file` ; `if [[ $(cat /some/file) == flip1 ]] ...`

Answer (score 0):

That is not the goal of the command "export". This command is only useful for the child processes (so they can see the exported variable(s)).

I would just use a file for this.

```
file=~/.screen # what you want
if grep -qx 1 "$file" # if "1" is found in the file
then
    echo "it was 1, save 0"
    echo 0 > "$file"
else
    echo "it was 0, save 1"
    echo 1 > "$file"
fi
```